# Reverse .class to original class type

Tags: java

With the following line of code:

```
List<Dao<?>> genericList = Dao.get(Person.class, q);
```

I call the following static method:

```
/**
 * Dynamically create list of generic Dao's 
 * @param className
 * @return
 */
public static List<Dao<?>> get(Class<?> classType, Query q){ 

    List<Dao<?>> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    try { 
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = Model.getAll(q); 

        for (Map<String, Object> map : results) { 
            Dao<?> obj = PojoFactory.createPojo(classType.getSimpleName()); 
            for (String key : map.keySet()) { 
                //Double check if field names exist before setting them 

                //http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
                BeanUtils.setProperty(obj, key, map.get(key)); 
            } 
            list.add(obj); 
        } 

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return list; 
}
```

Instead of returning a DAO type, I would like to return the correct type so that I don't need to cast afterwards.
In order to do so, I need to be able to reverse:

```
Person.class
```

to adapt this line:

```
List<Dao<?>> genericList = Dao.get(Person.class, q);
```

to the correct type so that I can call it like this:

```
List<Person> genericList = Dao.get(Person.class, q);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should introduce a type parameter in the method header.

```
public static <T extends Dao<T>> List<T> get(Class<T> classType, Query q){ 

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    try { 
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = Model.getAll(q); 

        for (Map<String, Object> map : results) { 
            T obj = (T) PojoFactory.createPojo(classType.getSimpleName()); 
            for (String key : map.keySet()) { 
                //Double check if field names exist before setting them 

                //http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
                BeanUtils.setProperty(obj, key, map.get(key)); 
            } 
            list.add(obj); 
        } 

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return list; 
}
```

I was assuming that the definition of Person looks like:

```
class Person extends Dao<Person> {
}
```